# Is it possible to have multi/custom field type inside a w2ui grid column with inline-editing for each type based on cell value?

Tags: w2ui

Is it possible to have a grid column containing multiple types inside of it based on the value of a cell? Where each cell is rendered based on value. For instance, with in the same column a cell could be of type 'text' or 'datetime' or 'list' etc... and for each type I can use built in inline-editing? See image illustration below. Basically a key/value editor where the value column need to contain more than one 'type. Please post a sample answer.

[image]

Comment: don't see the reason for negative votes. Legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it was a hack solution I ended up creating multiple grids aligned vertically each with a property & value column but the value column's 'type' attribute is different for each grid based on the w2ui framework out of box functionality I Desired for it. Each Grid is also separated by the header without padding to give it a feel like it is one grid. See Image below. now obviously the draw back of this is you cannot sort on all the fields but this is not required in my use case.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but you cannot rely on standard funtionality.

The idea of a w2grid is to assign a renderer to a column and render all cells of the same column in the same way.

You could implement a render function for your column and then generate the HTML for each cell based on those arguments:

http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.columns

Or you could override `getCellHTML()` for your grid.

Have a look at the implementation of `getCellHTML()` to see what awaits you if you want to customize it:

https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/blob/master/src/w2grid.js#L7396

Comment: thanks for the hints. I wanted the out of box functionality though like 'list', 'float', 'int', etc.. My current hack solution is I ended up creating multiple grids stacked on top of each other using the header as the divider. Where each grid has 1 value column of specific datatype